# Laravel display name from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a new problem. I'll try to give enough information.

I'm trying to display the names of the employees that have visited the customers, but as you can see it displays the names of the customers. Instead of Bryan or Granucci (these are the customers), it should say Madmin (I have only one user at the moment).

**Screenshot**
[This is the drafts page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKI0z.png)

I'll add the code form my view, controller and model.

**Drafts View**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

@include('nav')

<div class="container">

    @include('flash')

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">

            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'action' => 'DraftsController@create']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Create new draft', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">Search drafts</div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'drafts/search', 'method' => 'post')) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
                        {!! Form::label('customer_name', 'Customer:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('customer_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control typeahead tt-query', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'spellcheck' => 'false', 'placeholder' => 'Search...']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
                        {!! Form::label('customer_id', 'Customer ID:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        {!! Form::text('customer_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => 'readonly']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br><br>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
                        {!! Form::label('descr', 'Article:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {!! Form::text('descr', null, ['class' => 'form-control typeahead tt-query', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'spellcheck' => 'false', 'placeholder' => 'Search...']) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('reportgroup', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
                        {!! Form::label('article_id', 'Article ID:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        {!! Form::text('article_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => 'readonly']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br><br>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
                        {!! Form::label('reference', 'Reference:') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {!! Form::text('reference', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br><br>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
                        {!! Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                {!! Form::close() !!}

                @include('errors')

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'DraftsController@invoice']) !!}

                <div class="panel-heading">Search results</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Employee</th>
                            <th>Customer</th>
                            <th>Reference</th>
                            <th>Draft created</th>
                            <th>Work date</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right">Total excl. VAT</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $count = 0; ?>
                        @foreach ($result as $draft)
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="invoice_{{$draft['id']}}" name="invoice_{{$draft['id']}}"></td>
                                <td><a href="drafts/{{ $draft['id'] }}/edit">{{ $draft['id'] }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{$draft['name'] }} ({{ $draft['user_id'] }})</td>
                                <td>{{$draft['name'] }} ({{ $draft['customer_id'] }})</td>
                                <td><a href="drafts/{{ $draft['id'] }}/edit">{{ $draft['reference'] }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ $draft['created_at'] }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td style="text-align:right">{{ number_format($totals[$draft['id']],2) }}</td>
                                <td><input class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_{{$draft['id']}}" id="delete_{{$draft['id']}}" type="submit" value="X"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $count++ ?>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                    <?php
                    if ($count == 0) {
                        print "No results";
                    }
                    else {
                        ?>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {!! Form::submit('Create invoice for selected drafts', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;with invoice date&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control" name="createDate" type="date" id="createDate" value="{{date('Y-m-d')}}">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;and mail them to customer&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="mailThem" name="mailThem">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
@include('jsonArticles')
@include('jsonCustomers')

<script src="{{ asset('/js/typeahead.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/customers.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/articles.js') }}"></script>

@stop
```

**Draftsheader Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DraftHeader extends Model {

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function lines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DraftLine');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'employee_name',
        'customer_id',
        'name',
        'name2',
        'address',
        'postcode',
        'town',
        'country',
        'reference'
    ];

}
```

**Drafts Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Article;
use App\Customer;
use App\User;
use App\DraftHeader;
use App\DraftLine;
use App\InvoiceHeader;
use App\InvoiceLine;
use App\InvoiceMail;

use App\Http\Requests\DraftRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\DraftSearchRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\DraftLinesRequest;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class DraftsController extends Controller {
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | ArticlesController
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | Controller for Metis draft tasks
      |
     */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Get all articles
     *
     * @return array()
     */
    private function allArticles() {
        $allArticles = array();
        $ff = Article::All()->toArray();
        foreach ($ff as $ff1) {
            $allArticles[] = array('name' => $ff1['descr'], 'id' => $ff1['id']);
        }
        return $allArticles;
    }

    /**
     * Get all customers
     *
     * @return array()
     */
    private function allCustomers() {
        $allCustomers = array();
        $ff = Customer::All()->toArray();
        foreach ($ff as $ff1) {
            $allCustomers[] = array('name' => $ff1['name'], 'id' => $ff1['id']);
        }
        return $allCustomers;
    }

    /**
     * Get all uers
     *
     * @return array()
     */
    private function allUsers() {
        $allUsers = array();
        $ff = User::All()->toArray();
        foreach ($ff as $ff1) {
            $allUsers[] = array('name' => $ff1['name'], 'id' => $ff1['id']);
            //dd($allUsers);
        }
        return $allUsers;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index() {
        // Use request saved in session if applicable
        $result = array();

        if (Session::has('draft_search_request')) {
            $request = Session::get('draft_search_request');
            //dd($request);
            $result = DraftHeader::query();
            if (strlen(trim($request['customer'])) > 0) {
                $result->where('name', 'LIKE', "%" . $request['customer'] . "%");
            }
            if (strlen(trim($request['user'])) > 0) {
                $result->where('name', 'LIKE', "%" . $request['user'] . "%");
            }
            if (strlen(trim($request['reference'])) > 0) {
                $result->where('reference', 'LIKE', "%" . $request['reference'] . "%");
            }
            if (strlen(trim($request['article'])) > 0) {
                $result->DraftLine()->where('descr', 'LIKE', "%" . $request['article'] . "%");
            }
            //dd($result->toSql());
            $result = $result->get()->toArray();
            //dd($result);
        }
        else {
            $result = DraftHeader::query()->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::yesterday())->get()->toArray();
        }
        // Get the total amount for each draft draft
        $totals = array();
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $total = DraftLine::selectRaw('sum(qty*netamount) AS total')->where('draft_header_id', '=', $value['id'])->get()->toArray();
            $totals[$value['id']] = $total[0]['total'];
        }
        return view('drafts.search')->with('result', $result)->with('totals', $totals)->with('allArticles', $this->allArticles())->with('allCustomers', $this->allCustomers())->with('allUsers', $this->allUsers());
    }

    public function search(DraftSearchRequest $request) {
        //Put request in session variable to use in view
        $request1 = array('customer' => $request['customer'],'user' => $request['user'], 'reference' => $request['reference'], 'article' => $request['article']);
        if ($request1['customer'] == "" && $request1['user'] == "" &&  $request1['reference'] == "" && $request1['article'] == "") {
            session()->flash('draft_search_request', $request1);
        }
        else {
            Session::put('draft_search_request', $request1);
        }
        return redirect ('drafts');
    }

    public function invoice(Request $request) {
        //Create invoices for the selected drafts
        //dd($request);
        //dd($request->except('_token'));
        $number_of_invoices = 0;
        $draftdeleted = false;
        $mail = false;
        if (isset($request['mailThem']) && $request['mailThem'] == "on") {
            $mail = true;
        }
        $invoicedate = $request['createDate'];
        if (!checkdate(substr($invoicedate, 5, 2), substr($invoicedate, 8, 2), substr($invoicedate, 0, 4))) {
            $invoicedate = "";
        }

        foreach($request->except('_token') as $key => $val) {
            //dd($key);
            if (substr($key, 0, 8) == "invoice_" && $val == "on") {
                $draft_id = substr($key, 8);
                // Create the invoice
                // But only if there are lines
                $draftheader = DraftHeader::findOrFail($draft_id)->toArray();
                $draftlines = DraftHeader::findOrFail($draft_id)->lines()->get()->toArray();
                if (count($draftlines) > 0) {
                    // Create the invoice header
                    $invoiceheader = InvoiceHeader::create($draftheader);
                    if ($invoicedate != "") {
                        $invoiceheader->created_at = $invoicedate;
                        $invoiceheader->save();
                    }
                    // Create the invoice lines
                    foreach ($draftlines as $draftline) {
                        $newline = new InvoiceLine;
                        $newline->article_id = $draftline['article_id'];
                        $newline->descr = $draftline['descr'];
                        $newline->qty = $draftline['qty'];
                        $newline->grossamount = $draftline['grossamount'];
                        $newline->discount = $draftline['discount'];
                        $newline->netamount = $draftline['netamount'];
                        $newline->taxrate = $draftline['taxrate'];
                        $newline->addition = $draftline['addition'];
                        $newline = $invoiceheader->lines()->save($newline);
                    }
                    // Delete the draft
                    DraftHeader::destroy($draft_id);
                    $number_of_invoices++;

                    if ($mail) {
                        // Add the invoice to the create and send queue (no recipient = to be processed)
                        $invoicemail = new InvoiceMail;
                        $invoicemail = $invoiceheader->mail()->save($invoicemail);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (substr($key, 0, 7) == "delete_") {
                // Delete the selected draft
                $draft_id = substr($key, 7);
                DraftHeader::destroy($draft_id);
                session()->flash('flash_success', "Draft deleted");
                $draftdeleted = true;
            }
        }

        $andmailed = "";
        if ($number_of_invoices > 0 && $mail) {
            $andmailed = " and queued to be sent by mail";
        }

        if (!$draftdeleted) {
            session()->flash('flash_success', $number_of_invoices . " invoice(s) created " . $andmailed);
        }

        $request1 = array('customer' => $request['customer'], 'user' => $request['user'], 'reference' => $request['reference'], 'article' => $request['article']);
        if ($request1['customer'] == "" && ['user'] == "" && $request1['reference'] == "" && $request1['article'] == "") {
            session()->flash('draft_search_request', $request1);
        }
        else {
            Session::put('draft_search_request', $request1);
        }
        return redirect ('drafts');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create() {
        return view('drafts.create')->with('allCustomers', $this->allCustomers());
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(DraftRequest $request) {
        //dd($request);
        // Get the customer information
        /*
        $this->validate($request, [
            'reference' => 'required'
        ]);
         * 
         */
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($request['customer_id']);
        $pass = array_merge($request->all(), $customer->toArray());
        //dd($pass);
        DraftHeader::create($pass);

        //dd($request);
        // Get the user information
        /*
        $this->validate($request, [
            'reference' => 'required'
        ]);
         * 
         */
        $user = User::findOrFail($request['user_id']);
        $pass = array_merge($request->all(), $user->toArray());
        //dd($pass);
        DraftHeader::create($pass);

        return redirect('drafts');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id) {
        // Retrieve header and lines
        //dd($id);
        $draftheader = DraftHeader::findOrFail($id)->toArray();
        //dd($draftheader);

        $draftlines = DraftHeader::findOrFail($id)->lines()->get()->toArray();
        //dd($draftlines);
        // Get the draft's total
        $drafttotal = 0;
        $drafttotal_in = 0;
        foreach ($draftlines as $line) {
            $drafttotal = $drafttotal + ($line['qty'] * $line['netamount']);
            $drafttotal_in = $drafttotal_in + (($line['qty'] * $line['netamount']) / 100 * (100 + $line['taxrate']));
        }
        return view('drafts.edit')->with('header', $draftheader)->with('lines', $draftlines)->with('drafttotal', $drafttotal)->with('drafttotal_in', $drafttotal_in)->with('allArticles', $this->allArticles());
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
public function update($id, DraftLinesRequest $request) {
    //dd($request->all());
    // Save the draft header (again)
    $draftheader = DraftHeader::findOrFail($id);
    if ($draftheader->reference != $request['reference']) {
        $draftheader->reference = $request['reference'];
        $draftheader->save();
    }

    // Update the lines if there are changes
    $requestcopy = $request->All();
    reset($requestcopy);
    foreach ($requestcopy as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 11) == "grossamount") {
            $lineid = substr($key, 11);
            $draftline = Draftline::findOrFail($lineid);
            $v_descr = 'descr' . $lineid;
            $v_qty = 'qty' . $lineid;
            $v_grossamount = 'grossamount' . $lineid;
            $v_discount = 'discount' . $lineid;
            $v_addition = 'addition' . $lineid;

            if ($draftline->descr != $request[$v_descr] || $draftline->qty != $request[$v_qty] || $draftline->grossamount != $request[$v_grossamount] || $draftline->discount != $request[$v_discount] || $draftline->addition != $request[$v_addition]) {
                $draftline->descr = $request[$v_descr];
                $draftline->qty = $request[$v_qty];
                $draftline->addition = $request[$v_addition];
                $draftline->grossamount = $request[$v_grossamount];
                $draftline->discount = $request[$v_discount];
                $draftline->netamount = $draftline->grossamount - ($draftline->grossamount * ($draftline->discount/100)) + ($draftline->grossamount * ($draftline->addition/100));
                $draftline->save();
                session()->flash('flash_success', 'Update succeeded');
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if a line needs to be deleted
    reset($requestcopy);
    foreach ($requestcopy as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 6) == "cmdDel") {
            $lineid = substr($key, 6);
            $draftline = Draftline::findOrFail($lineid);
            $draftline->delete();
            session()->flash('flash_success', 'Draft line was deleted');

        }
    }

    // Check if a new line should be created
    if ($request['qty'] != 0 && $request['article_id'] > 0 && strlen($request['descr']) > 0) {
        $newline = new DraftLine;
        $article = Article::findOrFail($request['article_id']);
        $customer = $draftheader->customer;
        $newline->article_id = $request['article_id'];
        $newline->descr = $request['descr'];
        $newline->qty = $request['qty'];
        $newline->grossamount = $article->gross;
        $newline->discount = $customer->discount;
        $newline->taxrate = $article->taxrate;
        if ($customer->taxrate == "No tax") {
            $newline->taxrate = 0;
        }
        $newline->netamount = $newline->grossamount - ($newline->grossamount * ($newline->discount/100));
        $newline = $draftheader->lines()->save($newline);
        session()->flash('flash_success', 'New draft line was added');
    }

    return redirect('drafts/' . $id . '/edit');
}

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        //
    }

}
```

**User model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use App\Hour;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
        use Notifiable;
        use Eloquence;

        public function draftheaders()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\DraftHeader');
        }

        protected $searchableColumns = ['name'];
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

        public function hours()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Hour::class);
        }



}
```

**User controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function find(Request $request)
    {
        $term = trim($request->q);

        if (empty($term)) {
            return \Response::json([]);
        }

        $users = user::search($term)->limit(5)->get();

        $formatted_users = [];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $formatted_users[] = ['id' => $user->id, 'text' => $user->name];
        }

    return \Response::json($formatted_users);

        }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except('find');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('user');
    }
}
```

The database has the following tables:
[User table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOEE9.png), 
[Draftsheader table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqdIt.png)

> In the draftsheader table I changed the column user_id to index. And
>   in the users table I changed column name to index. Normally I would
>   index the column and give it a foreignkey. But I looked at the
>   customer table and the draftsheader table and there where no
>   foreignkeys. So I was thinking maybe foreignkeys arent nessecary, as
>   long as the fields are indexed.

I hope you guys can help me out, cause i'm stuck... If information is missing let me now and I'll edit the page.

**Update**
In the view I changed [¨name¨] to [¨employee_name¨] Like suggested by a fellow stackoverflow user. It resulted in this:
[Changed name to employee_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu9Sa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
     @foreach ($result as $draft)
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="invoice_{{$draft['id']}}" name="invoice_{{$draft['id']}}"></td>
                        <td><a href="drafts/{{ $draft['id'] }}/edit">{{ $draft['id'] }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{$draft['name'] }} ({{ $draft['user_id'] }})</td>
                        <td>{{$draft['name'] }} ({{ $draft['customer_id'] }})</td>
                        <td><a href="drafts/{{ $draft['id'] }}/edit">{{ $draft['reference'] }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{ $draft['created_at'] }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">{{ number_format($totals[$draft['id']],2) }}</td>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_{{$draft['id']}}" id="delete_{{$draft['id']}}" type="submit" value="X"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $count++ ?>
                @endforeach
```

To this:

```
         @foreach ($result as $draft)
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="invoice_{{$draft['id']}}" name="invoice_{{$draft['id']}}"></td>
                            <td><a href="drafts/{{ $draft['id'] }}/edit">{{ $draft['id'] }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{$draft['employee_name'] }} ({{ $draft['user_id'] }})</td>
                            <td>{{$draft['name'] }} ({{ $draft['customer_id'] }})</td>
                            <td><a href="drafts/{{ $draft['id'] }}/edit">{{ $draft['reference'] }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ $draft['created_at'] }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{{ number_format($totals[$draft['id']],2) }}</td>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_{{$draft['id']}}" id="delete_{{$draft['id']}}" type="submit" value="X"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $count++ ?>
                    @endforeach
```

You use ['name'] two times, but you have the customer_name on it.

Comment: I changed [¨name¨] to employee_name. now it just displays (0). It goes wrong somewhere in the drafts controller public function index, I think.

Comment: What is your database table like?

Comment: I´ve posted a picture in my main post, at the bottom. so you can see the outcome.

Comment: Thank you, I see!

Comment: In my main post I posted a picture of the database. Or would you want to see other tables aswell?

Comment: What is your search query? Or is this using the else?

Comment: I didn´t write this code, a former intern did. But where could I find the query, in the drafts controller?

Comment: And iḿ new to laravel btw haha